# Image control stretch property not working in Windows phone8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I just tried to bind a BitMapImage as the source of an Image control in my windows phone 8 application. And apply the Stretch property to Uniform. But the image is still showing stretched. How can I fit the image in it's original dimension.

Here is my code:

```
<Image x:Name="ConversationImage" Width="200" Height="200" Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility}" Source="{Binding ThumbImage}" Stretch="Uniform"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello Deepak your image is showing stretched because you set its strech property to uniform if you it to be in original dimention just set stretch property to none..

```
<Image x:Name="ConversationImage" Width="200" Height="200" Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility}" Source="{Binding ThumbImage}" Stretch="None"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

if you want it always in its original dimension just remove your image control width and height.